# CI Multi Value insert

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I use jquery append for more fields in CI. But Don't know How to to insert multi value into the Db. Please help me.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$tr="<tr><td><input type='input' name='title' /></td><td><textarea name='text'></textarea></td></tr>"; 
   $("#btn2").click(function(){
    $("#tb").append($tr);
  });
});
</script>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<button id="btn2">add New</button>
<?php echo form_open('welcome/create'); ?>

    <table id="tb" width="100%">
  <tr>
      <td>Title
         </td>
         <td>Text
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" />
</form>
```

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/create_news_items.html

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should start by giving all fields an individual name, and loop over all elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make You input/textarea field as array:

```
<tr><td><input type='input' name='title[]' /></td><td><textarea name='text[]'></textarea></td></tr>
```

In php controller:

```
//Load model 
//Pass Post data to model function
$this->model_name->function_name($_POST);
```

In php model:

```
function_name($data)
{
  $name_arr = $data['name'];
  $text_arr = $data['text'];
  for($i=0;$i<count($name_arr);$i++)
  {
    //Insert query with values like $name_arr[$i],$text_arr[$i];
  }
}
```

Note: Still you are not able to understand then go through CI Tutorials.

Comment: How to use in this tutorial https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/create_news_items.html

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Use `[]` with the name attribute of an input field

```
$tr = "<tr><td><input type='input' name='title[]' /></td><td><textarea name='text[]'></textarea></td></tr>";
```

This will take all the values as an array from input field having the same name attribute

Comment: Hoe to use in this tutorial https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/create_news_items.html

Comment: Basically, what do you want to do?